# Partial Derivative of e^x with respect to x

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function, partial-derivative, exponentiation

I was asked to find $\frac{\delta e^x}{\delta x}$. I thought that it would simply be $e^x$, as there is no $y$, so I could just differentiate as normal. However, the correct answer was $e^x \log{x}$. I searched it up on the internet, but I couldn't find any results. All the sites were talking about the chain rule, but I don't understand why I would need the chain rule here. Can anybody help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact question you were asked? Seems like something is missing.

Comment: The derivative of $e^x$ is indeed itself - maybe there's an error in your textbook? There's certainly no elementary, single-variable function whose derivative is $e^x\log x$

Comment: "*correct answer was $e^x \log{x}$*" $\;$ Was that $e^x \log{e}$ maybe, and was $e$ defined to be something other than the base of natural logarithms? Some more context would help here.

Comment: FYI - it doesn't make sense to talk about the "partial" derivative of a single variable function. That is just a derivative, there is nothing partial about it. For functions of multiple variables, derivatives are "partial" because the result depends on the complete set of variables that can change, not just on the particular variable that you are differentiating with respect to. If they are calling this a "partial derivative", there should be more than one thing varying.

Comment: @Paul, the exercise was to find the partial derivative of $e^x + sin(y)$, but the $sin(y)$ yields no information. Also, can you please explain why, when dealing with $e^{\text{something}}$ we need to use the chain rule? Thanks :)

Comment: $\sin y$ does provide information. The information it provides is that this term does not depend on $x$. Of course this was already obvious, but that does not change what it tells you. You use the change rule to differentiate $e^\text{something}$ because this is exactly the situation the chain rule covers. The chain rule says that the derivative of $\text{otherthing}(\text{\something})$ is $\text{something}'\cdot \text{otherthing}'(\text{something})$. In this case, $\text{otherthing}(x) = e^x$.

Comment: Just to make sure what has been said is clear. The *real* correct answer to $\dfrac{\partial(e^x + \sin y)}{\partial x}$ is $e^x$ as you had calculated. $e^x\log x$ is wrong. How it went wrong we cannot say. It could be that there was a mix-up in which answer goes with which problem, or it could be that the problem was changed but they forgot to change the answer, or it could be that the problem was different, but somebody mistyped it.

Comment: Okay, thank you :)